# List reversal and formatting in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Completely new to Angular. I have this:

```
<input ng-model="mysequence" ng-list>

<span>{{mysequence}}</span>
```

which turns `1,2,3` into `["1","2","3"]`

What's the best (easiest or most idiomatic) way to

1. reverse the list
2. format it

in this interesting framework? For example: `3! 2! 1!`

Comment: how did you declare `mysequence`?

Comment: I didn't - just added what you see to angular-seed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `orderBy` like this :

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy:'id':true">
        <span>{{item.value}}</span>!
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        id: 1,
        value: '1'},{
        id: 2,
        value: '2'}];
}
```

Comment: Using an object with properties (which seems necessary to use orderBy) for the model means I can't use ng-list, so this isn't a solution as far as I can see.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `orderBy` filter (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy) to reverse the list, and to create a custom filter to handle formatting, something like

```
angular.module('myApp')
.filter('formatNumbers', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input + "!";
    };
});
```

With this, you should be able to do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="i in mysequence | orderBy::true">
    {{i|formatNumbers}}
</div>
```